# How to insert data with sum of a few column to same table column

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have a bills table which has columns like

```
id     dish_bill     electric_bill     telephone_bill     mobile_bill     total
```

I want to insert data in each column. When I will submit data, the sum of all column will insert in total field in every row.

### My Code is:

```
<?php
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "bill";

if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
$dishBill = $_POST['dish'];
$electricBill = $_POST['electric'];
$telephoneBill = $_POST['telephone'];
$mobileBill = $_POST['mobile'];

$query = "insert into     bills(dish_bill,electric_bill,telephone_bill,mobile_bill,total) values ($dishBill,$electricBill,$telephoneBill,$mobileBill,sum($dishBill+$electricBill+$telephoneBill+$mobileBill))";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPassword,$dbName);
mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
Dish Bill: <input type="text" name="dish">
Electric Bill: <input type="text" name="electric">
Telephone Bill: <input type="text" name="telephone">
Mobile Bill: <input type="text" name="mobile">
<input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>
```

Comment: what you tried share code

Answer (score 0):

What is sum() in your query? SQL SUM() function is used in SELECT statement.

You can just count sum before query like

```
$sum = $dishBill + $electricBill + $telephoneBill + $mobileBill;
```

and then in query use `$sum` instead of `sum($dishBill+$electricBill+$telephoneBill+$mobileBill)`

Also when counting `$sum` make sure to convert your values to integer or float or whatever you need   (for example for float `floatval($dishBill)` etc)